# Баг в цикле, debug-сборка

Tags: c++

[MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
int main()
{
    const int maxLenght = 10;
    int arr[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    int count = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < maxLenght; ++i )
        if( arr[i] == 1 )
            count++;

    return 0;
}
```

Вот такой незамысловатый пример. С отключенной оптимизацией. В дебажной сборке перед выходом значение `count` равно 1. Почему так происходит ?

Comment: В отладчике также? Чем arr заполнен?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, в нем и есть. Сейчас посмотрели - он "прыгает" с оператора на return, потом - обратно. И так, пока действительно count не станет равным 10. Т.е. если поставить брейкпоинт на return, то сложится ощущение, что count равен 1, на самом же деле программа продолжит работать дальше.

Comment: Таким образом, на ожидаемые результаты это не повлияет, но отладку - затруднит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, так из примера видно же, чем он заполнен.

Comment: Какой компилятор, какие ключи? Значение по сути не используется. Может использование `volatile` что-то изменит. Но смысла в этом всё равно не вижу, т.к. на видимое поведение программы влияния нет.

Comment: А вы выведите это значение перед выходом :)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то у вас не то с отладчиком :) Вот этот код в трёх отладчиках/IDE, в двух вариантах: во время пошагового исполнения, и с прогоном до точки останова у return.

1. **CLion**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. **Nemiver**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. **Eclipse**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все значения видны во всех случаях. Но для надёжности я бы попробовал обернуть все однострочники в фигурные скобки, может некоторым отладчикам (или их гуям) так понятней станет:

```
for( i = 0; i < sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] ); ++i ) {
    if( arr[i] == 1 ) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я и не спорю, с дебаггером проблемы ) Ошибку зарепортили, что ответят - скоро узнаем )

Comment: @isnullxbh, а если всё-таки в фигурные скобки всё  завернуть?

Comment: Тогда все хорошо, конечно. Вообще, наличие любого оператора после оператора ```for``` спасает нас от этой баги. Ее как бы и багой-то не назовешь - но даже чисто визуально, наблюдать, как курсор прыгает с тела ```for``` на ```return```, а потом - обратно - не очень приятно.

Comment: @isnullxbh, так а что за отладчик такой хитрый?

Comment: Дебаггер в VS2013 ))))